# Getting null values in asp.net mvc model when passing values through angular js

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-2

I have created model in asp.net mvc with constructor to create new guid id for ID field which inherits from base class. Now i pass values for two parameters of the model other than ID from html page using angular js while calling the $http.post service. At web api I am receiving the null values only id is getting generated.

Model:

```
public class EngineeringTeamDTO : Entity
{   
    public EngineeringTeamDTO() : base()
    {

    }
    public EngineeringTeamDTO(Guid ID) : base(ID)
    {

    }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String TeamName { get; set; }

    public String Note { get; set; }
}
```

Web api

```
public IHttpActionResult PostEngineeringTeamDTO(EngineeringTeamDTODemo engineeringTeamDTO)
{
    //code
}
```

So here in this web api I am getting null values for `TeamName` and Note parameter when calling the web api through the angular js. If i remove the constructor from model it works fine. But constructor is needful for me.

Angular Code:

```
   $scope.addteam = function (ETD) {
    debugger


    $http.post($rootScope.addEngTeam, ETD).success(function (data) {
        alert("ADDED")

    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.Space = "Error" + data;
    });

}
```

Html Code:

```
  <input type="text"   name="TeamName" ng-model="ETD1.TeamName" required  />
                                <input type="text"  name="Note" ng-model="ETD1.Note" required />
      <input type="button" value="Add"  ng-click="addteam(ETD1)"/>
```

Comment: What's your angularjs code?

Comment: Hey please check it now.